# xpath not return values

Tags: php, xpath, foreach, simplexml

I am able to pull the necessary information using xpath, when I use `var_dump` using the following code. When I try to add a foreach loop to return all `["href"]` values i get a blank page any ideas where I am messing up?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($source);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
$rss = $xml->xpath("/html/body//a[@class='highzoom1']");

$links = $rss->href;

foreach ($links as $link){ 
    echo $link; 
    }
```

Here is the array of information.

```
array(96) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (2) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["href"]=>
      string(49) "/p/18351/test1.html"
      ["class"]=>
      string(10) "highzoom1"
    }
    [0]=>
    string(36) ""test1"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (2) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["href"]=>
      string(43) "/p/18351/test2.html"
      ["class"]=>
      string(10) "highzoom1"
    }
    [0]=>
    string(30) ""test2"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (2) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["href"]=>
      string(48) "/p/18351/test3.html"
      ["class"]=>
      string(10) "highzoom1"
    }
    [0]=>
    string(35) ""test3"
  }
```

Comment: could you please post in the contents of the original XML for reference?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a short and simple one-liner XPath solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Instead of**:

```
$rss = $xml->xpath("/html/body//a[@class='highzoom1']");
```

**use**:

```
$hrefs = $xml->xpath("/html/body//a[@class='highzoom1']/@href");
```

The original XPath expression (the first above) you are using selects any `a` element in the XML document the value of whose `class` atribute is `'highzoom1'` and that (the `a` element) is a descendent of a `body` that is a child of the top element (named `html`) in the XML document.

However, you want to select the `href` attributes of these `a` elements -- not the `a` elements themselves.

**The second XPath expression above select exactly the `href` attributes of these `a` elements**.

Comment: your example gave me `array(0) { }` when i used var_dump($hrefs);

Comment: @sarsar: If so, this means that Simple XML isn't a compliant XPath engine. I can help you with XPath but not with incompliant implementations of XPath. Please, retag and remove the "xpath" tag and add "simplexml tag.

Comment: @sarsar: glad to hear this. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$links = $rss->href;
```

will never work, as $rss is a DOMNodeList object, and won't have an href attribute. Instead, you'd want to do this:

```
$rss = $xml->xpath("/html/body//a[@class='highzoom1']");

foreach($rss as $link) {
    echo $link->href;
}
```

Or you can address $rss as an array directly:

```
echo $rss[5]->href; // echo out the href of the 6th link found.
```